Bone Roll with IK not working as expected
I was trying to apply weights to my mesh and I discovered that the "roll" (not sure if that is the best term) for the thigh bone is off by 90 degrees. When I disable the IK restraint on the leg bone, the "roll" is back to what I want it at. I don't know how to fix it.
The leg to the right of the view is without the IK constraint but the one to the left is.
Edit:

This is what it looks like with iterations set to zero. The thigh still ends up getting rotated without any of the IK transforms of the bones.
Edit:

If I set pole to 90 degrees the knee points the wrong way but the thigh is in the correct roll.

If I move the knee target the knee can point in the right way but i would be back with the thigh with the glitchy looking roll direction.
Side Pictures:

What I want out (Manually transformed)

What I get with IK
Link To Current File If Available:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dwb4liUP023qHRGYyDyI7D3yY6lJ_PSR/view?usp=sharing

Do the following things:

In Edit mode, bend the knees a bit forwards so that it knows in what direction it is supposed to bend
Still in Edit mode, put the pole target bones in front of the knees:


In Pose mode set the Pole Angle value of your IK constraint to -90:


That only changes the direction that the knee faces. The knee is already facing the correct way but the thigh bone, which im concerned with, has a roll applied by this constraint that causes the thigh to bend in an awkward way which is unwanted. It led to the mesh to clip through itself in a 90 degree rotation along the bone's diameter. If you look at the leg to the left you would see that it looks off compared to the leg to the right. Anyways thanks for your input.

@Brigham Peterson Moonboots is right.  Try it.  It's easy to get a misconception about what the pole does.  If it doesn't work, we need a file.  But-- try it.

I added images showing a different pole angle. All I understand with my current knowledge on the IK constraint controls the direction the joint points.

@Nathan I got the file in the newest post edit.

I've edited my answer

I found out that adjusting bone roll, pole angle does not solve the problem but to moving the joint between the thigh and leg out fixed it. I think this is because blender needed to have so sort of rotation to already exist for it to work properly.

Why was this downvoted, I made this answer before moonboot edited their answer. My post was made 9 hours ago Moonboots edit that has the correct answer was made 6 hours ago.
